# Validity of .LESS code

Tags: less

I got a .less file and it has codes written in this fashion:

```
.btn-form{
    .button-toggle( @brand-black; @brand-white; @btnform-color; @btnform-hover-color; @border-color);
}
```

What does this code mean?

Comment: also refer to http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature-not-outputting-the-mixin for the use of parentheses and http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature-mixins-with-multiple-parameters for explanation of parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, `.button-toggle` is a [mixin](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature), declared elsewhere in your code (possibly an imported Less file). The declaration *might* be something like:

```
.button-toggle(@brand-black; @brand-white; @btnform-color; @btnform-hover-color; @border-color) {
    background: @btnform-color;
    color: @brand-black;
    &:hover {
        background: @btnform-hover-color;
        color: @brand-white;
    }
    border-color: @border-color;
    // other CSS properties or nested selectors
 }
```

It receives as parameters several [variables](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature), which should also be declared somewhere *before* you call the mixin, like:

```
@brand-black: black;
@brand-white: #fff;
@btnform-color: blue;
@btnform-hover-color: red;
@border-color: rgb(255,255,0);
```

You are *calling* the mixin when you place it inside a block, as you did, and it will generate CSS according to its definition and the parameters you are passing.

For example, if you call *your* code block preceded by those variable declarations *and* the mixin declaration I included above in a LESS compiler such as the online service http://lesstester.com/ you will get this CSS result:

```
.btn-form {
  background: #0000ff;
  color: #000000;
  border-color: #ffff00;
}
.btn-form:hover {
  background: #ff0000;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```